# Get Facebook story viewers using Facebook graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am new to Facebook graph API. I found out the API gives us powerful capabilities to read/write data using Facebook user or page access token but I can`t find any section that talks about dealing with Facebook stories, reading their viewers' accounts. I have found Instagram API which gives me the capability to deal with stories but this is for Instagram stories only.
So is there any right way to interact with Facebook stories?

Comment: You can not get any info about people who view your stories on an individual level.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find any way to do this. Thanks.